# Docker - EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, docker, nestjs

I have a dockerized NestJS application.

Dockerfile

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set to dev environment
ENV NODE_ENV dev

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# In order to run `npm run build` we need access to the Nest CLI which is a dev dependency. In the previous development stage we ran `npm ci` which installed all dependencies, so we can copy over the node_modules directory from the development image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Run the build command which creates the production bundle
RUN npm run build

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Running `npm ci` removes the existing node_modules directory and passing in --only=production ensures that only the production dependencies are installed. This ensures that the node_modules directory is as optimized as possible
RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

# Copy the bundled code from the build stage to the production image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      target: development
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
```

package.json

```
scripts: {
    "dev": "nest start --watch -b swc",
}
```

After running `docker-compose up -d`, I run `docker logs -f backend` and then an error shows.

```
docker logs -f backend

> backend@0.0.1 dev
> nest start --watch -b swc

>  SWC  Running...
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/dist'
...
Failed to compile 28 files with swc.
Watching for file changes.
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

I guess it's related to user access.
Tried to add `RUN chown -R node.node /app` in Dockerfile, but it doesn't work.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: `I guess it's related to user access` you're right. `How to fix this issue?` fix permissions

Comment: Because of the `volumes:` mounts, pretty much nothing you do in the Dockerfile has an effect.  You're fundamentally running Node in a semi-isolated environment, where you can't directly use basic commands like `npm`, but against code that lives only on the host.  Does using Docker in this setup actually bring any benefits, or can you directly run `node` on the host?  If you want to Dockerize the application, can you delete the `volumes:` and `command:` from the Compose file to run the application built into the image?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding

```
RUN chown -R node.node /usr/src/app
```

in the `Dockerfile`

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set to dev environment
ENV NODE_ENV dev

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

RUN chown -R node.node /usr/src/app <-----------------HERE
...
```